Can't Route ClickOnce Client Traffic through Proxy
I am testing two ClickOnce clients on Windows 10. I want to route the traffic through a web proxy (Burp). I'm able to do this for one of the clients but not the other.
For some reason, the traffic from the second application won't route according to my proxy settings. Both clients should be making similar network calls but I can only see the traffic from one passing through the proxy.
I've tried the setting up the proxy:

through the UI
using netsh winhttp set proxy <proxy>:<port>
through Internet Options/Edge, then using netsh winhttp import proxy source =ie
this: Using PowerShell to programmatically configure Internet Explorer proxy settings to work before it has been opened

All of this works for the one ClickOnce client but not the other.
I test these kinds of applications frequently and have never run into this. I'm really stumped! Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
